# Transform forEach in Promise (without ASYC/AWAIT)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to transform a `forEach` in promise. The code is legacy and I can't use async/await operators.

```
Promise.all(Object.entries(data).forEach(function (data) {
        let [data1, data2] = data
        let info;

        consultData.getResponse(data1).then(result => info = result).then(function () {
            return dataServices.find(info)
                .then(function (result) {
                    // do things
                })
                .then(function (info) {
                    // do final things
                })
        })
    })).then((result) => {
            // do something when all things have intereted and finished
        })
```

But output that `Promise.all` can't be used.  If I try with `Promise.resolve`, the last is printed before all things have finished their processing.

How I can transform the `forEach` in a promise for i can use .then() after all iteration?

ASYNC/AWAIT DON'T WORK IN THIS CODE

Comment: That's not the right way to use `Promise.all`. Try something along the lines of `Promise.all(Object.entries(data).map(... return somePromise ...))`

Comment: this can be achieved using `reduce` method of array

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the flagged question.  User cannot use async/await in their code for legacy reasons (if mods ever actually read questions..)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 the answer is still the same. The only caveat is that `consultData.getResponse(data1).then(...)` must be _returned_ from the function after changing `forEach()` to `map()`. I'm happy to find additional duplicates but this exact question has definitely been asked many times before.

Comment: People, async/await do'nt work in this code..... I told....

Comment: Change for map don't work too :(

Comment: ITS NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts this question it is not duplicate, i can use async/await in this code......